# How to understand the Cifar10 prediction output?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have trained `Cifar10`([caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/)) model for two classes classification. Pedestrian and non-pedestrian. Training looks fine, I have updated weights in a `caffemodel` file. I used two labels 1 for pedestrians and 2 for non-pedestrians, together with images for pedestrians (64 x 160) and background images (64 x 160).
After training, I do testing with positive image(pedestrian image) and negative image (background image). My testing `prototxt` file is as shown below

```
name: "CIFAR10_quick_test"
layers 
{
  name: "data"
  type: MEMORY_DATA
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  memory_data_param 
  {
    batch_size: 1
    channels: 3
    height: 160
    width: 64
  }
  transform_param 
  {
    crop_size: 64
    mirror: false
    mean_file: "../../examples/cifar10/mean.binaryproto"
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
  }
}
layers {
  name: "pool1"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu1"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "pool1"
}
layers {
  name: "conv2"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu2"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layers {
  name: "pool2"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: AVE
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv3"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu3"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layers {
  name: "pool3"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: AVE
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "ip1"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "ip1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 64
  }
}
layers {
  name: "ip2"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
  }
}
layers {
  name: "prob"
  type: SOFTMAX
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "prob"
}
```

For testing, I used `test_predict_imagenet.cpp` and did some modifications especially for paths and image size.

I can't figure out the test output. When I test with positive image, I got the output as

```
I0813 01:55:30.378114  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1
I0813 01:55:30.379082  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 3.90971e-007
I0813 01:55:30.381088  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 0.00406029
I0813 01:55:30.383090  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 0.995887
I0813 01:55:30.384119  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1.96203e-006
I0813 01:55:30.385095  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 3.50333e-005
I0813 01:55:30.386119  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1.2796e-008
I0813 01:55:30.387097  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1.48836e-005
I0813 01:55:30.389093  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1.12237e-007
I0813 01:55:30.390100  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 4.71238e-008
I0813 01:55:30.391101  7668 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 9.04134e-008
```

When I test with a negative image, I got the output as

```
I0813 01:53:40.896139 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1
I0813 01:53:40.897117 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 6.20882e-006
I0813 01:53:40.898115 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 7.10468e-005
I0813 01:53:40.900184 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 0.999911
I0813 01:53:40.901185 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 3.4275e-006
I0813 01:53:40.902189 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 2.38526e-007
I0813 01:53:40.903192 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 2.29073e-007
I0813 01:53:40.905187 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1.7243e-006
I0813 01:53:40.906188 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 5.40765e-007
I0813 01:53:40.908195 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 1.57534e-006
I0813 01:53:40.909195 10856 test_predict_cifarnet.cpp:72] 3.72312e-006
```

How to understand the testing output?

Is there any more effecient testing algorithm for testing the model from video feed (frame by frame from video clip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have `num_output: 10` for the last layer `ip2`? you only need 2-way classifier? Why are you using labels 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1?

**What you got**: You have 11 outputs: one is the `"label"` output from the data layer, and the other 10 outputs are the 10-vector output of the softmax layer. It is unclear what the values of the 10-vector are since you only trained using two labels, thus 8 out of 10 entries were not supervised at all. Moreover, judging by the first output it seems both tests were samples with label `1` and not `2`.

**What you should do:**
1. Change the topmost fully connected layer to have only two outputs (I also changed the format to match the new version protobuff)

```
layer {
  name: "ip2/pedestrains"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2 # This is what you need changing
  }
}
```

2. Change the binary labels in your training data to 0/1 rather that 1/2.

Now you can train again and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks Shai, now I understood. In the original prototxt is               blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2,                                                                                        and you replaced with                                                                     param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  } what is the difference?

Comment: @batuman there are several changes w.r.t. old prototxt. notice that "`layers`" is now just "`layer`", the `'type:'` is a string and not an enumeration and `blobs_lr` and `deacy_mult` are now under `param` for each blob.

Comment: Thanks Shai, should I change to all layers or only topmost layer is enough?

Comment: to move to new prototxt format you can use the utility `./build/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text`

Comment: @batuman As for structural changes in the net - only the top most FC layer should be changed to reflect the change from 10 classes classification to binary classification.

Comment: Thanks Shai. currently I am using test_predict_imagenet.cpp to test the trained model for a single image. But real application will be on a video clip and running frame by frame, is there any more efficient program or algorithm or method to run through video clip in frame by frame?

Comment: @batuman - this is a new question you should ask it in a new post.

Comment: Thanks Shai. Yeah I should.

Comment: @batuman feel free to link the new question to this one if you feel it gives more context. Otherwise, a fresh new question is also Okay.

Comment: Hi Shan, for both negative and positive images in testing, I always got label is 1 and values are 0.5 and 0.5. Whatever image I input, I got the same result. What does it mean?

Comment: Yes I did trained with two outputs.

Comment: Sorry it is working now. I forgot to change number of outputs is 2 at training :)

Comment: Thanks Shai, I have another query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992971/detecting-pedestrian-using-caffenet-model-at-moderate-framerate  if you have idea. Thanks