# Detecting pedestrian using CaffeNet model at moderate framerate

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I train the CaffeNet ([more precisely Cifar10 model for two classes classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972448/how-to-understand-the-cifar10-prediction-output)) model. Now the model is ready for detection. For the model testing with a single image, I use `test_predict_imagenet.cpp`. I haven't tested how fast the code can run for 640 x 480 image. My target is I like to have 5~10 frame/sec is just nice for offline detection. I understand that I need to implement multi-size detection (i.e. something like we do in face detection, original image size is re-sized for different smaller sizes) so that I don't miss the pedestrian in each frame.

According to this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.05790.pdf), they use 64 x 128 image size in training and detection takes 3ms/window and for 100 windows/image, it takes 300msec/frame. Not sure they implement multi-size detection approach. If multi-size is implemented, it will take much longer.

At this moment, I have only knowledge of implementing `test_predict_imagenet.cpp` method for multi-size detection. I know it will be very slow.
Is there any more efficient way of detection using CaffeNet model? My target is just nice for 5~10 frame/sec rate. Thanks

Comment: look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497

Comment: Thanks I got some ideas now. Later I'll discuss. People use cascade approach. Still haven't decided which design to use. Let me explore first.